# Why doesn't pymongo.encryption encrypt?

Tags: mongodb, encryption, pymongo

```
fle_opts = AutoEncryptionOpts(kms_providers, key_vault_namespace,
                              schema_map=patient_schema,**extra_options)
client = MongoClient(connection_string,
                     auto_encryption_opts=fle_opts)

client.encryption.coleccion_encriptada.insert_one(doc)
```

I'm running this to encrypt a document but when I see the base in Robo, can I see all the fields without encryption, will you know the reason?

I am using Mongo Enterprise

Comment: Are you referring to the below documentation, it seems you have taken the code snippet from the same page.

https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/client-side-field-level-encryption-guide/#insert-a-document-with-encrypted-fields

The example clearly states that you can not see the original value in Robo after it is encrypted and inserted.

The data is encrypted at the client side

Comment: Yes, I am using the tutorial, https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/client-side-field-level-encryption-guide/  Maybe I am not understanding how it works, I am running an app (pymongo) that should send encrypted data to a remote base, when I consult the base as a client (from another computer) the fields are not encrypted, there they should be, isn't it?

Comment: if you create a MongoClient(connection_string, auto_encryption_opts=fle_opts) with auto_encryption_opts, then you should see decrypted data, if you just create a normal MongoClient with just the connection string, then you should see the encrypted data.
Refer this link for the same https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/client-side-field-level-encryption-guide/#verify-that-the-data-encryption-key-was-created

Comment: Yes, I run: connection_string = URI_CONNECTION
client = MongoClient(connection_string)
coleccion = client['base_encriptada']['coleccion_encriptada']
busqueda = coleccion.find()
for i in busqueda:
    print(i),              and I see my data without encryption. Thanks for answering!!

Comment: This is my scribt  https://github.com/uzielsanchez/pymongo_encript/blob/master/prueba.py